# What is the synonym of the word focus here?

Tags: synonyms

I wonder if there are any synonyms of the word focus here? As far as I get the phrase "bring into focus" means "draw attention to", but other sentences are not very clear to me.
 I guess the closest definition will be
 a :  a center of activity, attraction, or attention  OR
b :  a point of concentrationhttp://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/focus

"Flow helps some of the world's most creative companies streamline their communication by bringing all parts of it into focus. This focus isn't just something we do, it's something we believe in—and certainly something I've been trying to practice on a regular basis since my time studying with Thích Nhất Hạnh".

Comment: You cannot "do" a focus or "believe in" a focus. That's marketing-speak.

Comment: "Bring into focus" does not mean "draw attention to".  It means "make clearer", as when you focus a telescope.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It seems that for the author, the "focus" word in

> This focus isn't just something we do

acts as a noun describing the action of "bringing into focus" (in the sense of your option *a)*).

You could compare it with how "treatment" is the act of treating, for example, though I'm not sure this use of "focus" as the action of bringing into focus is very correct because in the dictionaries it doesn't appear.

Comment: Underscoring the words "for the author".